# How do I break a loop when there are two consecutive similar numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop, break

I'd like to use `break` with for loop, 
At any time in the list, there might be a similar number as the previous one.

for examples:

```
x1 = [2,12,43,56,65,34,76,6,77,77,77,77,77,5,6,4,31]
x2 = [2,12,43,56,65,34,76,6,88,88,88,88,88,5,6,4,31]
x3 = [2,12,43,56,65,34,76,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,4,31]
```

how to use `break` when i ==77 in x1 , i == 88 in x2 and i ==5, this mean when sequenatial two  values the same, make break.

**Note**: I have more data and I don't open them. So, I don't know any number the sensor repeats it.

I thought use index with values but fail.

Please help or any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the last value you processed and if you see it again, you can just break from the loop

```
x1 = [2,12,43,56,65,34,76,6,77,77,77,77,77,5,6,4,31]
x2 = [2,12,43,56,65,34,76,6,88,88,88,88,88,5,6,4,31]
x3 = [2,12,43,56,65,34,76,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,4,31]

last_seen = -1

for x in [x1, x2, x3]:
  for current_number in x:
    if current_number == last_seen:
      last_seen = -1
      break

    print current_number.
    last_seen = current_number
  print
```

Repl: https://repl.it/repls/MisguidedReliableNotification